# How to enable HttpOnly to ApplicationGatewayAffinityCORS and ApplicationGatewayAffinity cookies in Azure Application Gateway?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, azure-application-gateway, httponly

How to enable HttpOnly to ApplicationGatewayAffinityCORS and ApplicationGatewayAffinity cookies in Azure Application Gateway HTTP settings configuration for a ASP. Net Web application response header? Please help

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/configuration-http-settings) and [this answered question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/513199/how-to-mark-azure-application-gateway-cookie-based.html) it seems this is not possible yet. Their page says:

> Some vulnerability scans may flag the Applicaton Gateway affinity
> cookie because the Secure or HttpOnly flags are not set. These scans
> do not take into account that the data in the cookie is generated
> using a one-way hash. The cookie does not contain any user information
> and is used purely for routing.

I want the same feature to be able to clear my vulnerability scanners, but doesn't seem like it's possible yet.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this command:

```
Set-Cookie: cookie_name="cookie_value"; HttpOnly
```

If your project is based on `.net framework`, consider adding the following to your `web.config` file, which would make sure that any cookies set by your application were `HttpOnly` :

```
<system.web>
    <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true"/>
</system.web>
```

You could also setting a cookie manually like below:

```
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(
    "CookieKey",
    "CookieValue",
    new CookieOptions
    {
        HttpOnly = true
    });
```

Comment: The OP is asking about a cookie set from the Azure Application Gateway load balancer. This is not something you can control through a web.config or C# code, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

[The answer by Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70699579/2157640) is straight to the point. It explains what the cookies are, and why their configuration is OK. The security scanners are just tools and they are not always right -- their results need interpretation. For now, the solution is just to **ignore the warning and keep the cookies as they are**.

But **if you do not need session affinity** on the Application Gateway, just **turn the cookies off altogether**. You don't need them if your application does not store the session state on the application server -- it uses a shared storage/DB for that, it stores it on the client side (protected by a MAC and possibly timestamps), or it has no session state at all.

To turn off the session affinity cookies, set the [Application Gateway resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.network/applicationgateways?pivots=deployment-language-bicep)'s properties.backendHttpSettingsCollection.properties.cookieBasedAffinity to "Disabled", e.g. using an ARM template, Azure CLI, or whatever your favorite interface to ARM is.